# Is it best practice currently to not use alternate box models?

Tags: html, css

I am currently beginning my forays into HTML and CSS. Already I have become frustrated at the standard box model setup where padding adds to the size of the box itself, so I've set in my CSS templating to use border-box models. Is this ok, or is it not recommended as a best practice / not recommended for learning HTML/CSS? Will many javascript/jQuery scripts break if I use it rather than the standard box model? I don't want to get into the habit of using it if most developers shy away from it or if it will cause pre-made scripts and plugins to break.

The reason I am asking this is because it seems like there are some people who are disgruntled with the current box-model, and if there are any signs that the standard box model might be changing to the border-box model, then I may want to stick with it.

Comment: You can change the used box model? How?

Comment: @Paŭlo use box-sizing: (attribute); (CSS3 only)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. (I didn't use much CSS lately, even less CSS 3.)

Comment: @Caedar That's some crazy stuff. I honestly think that once you get used to the box model the technique used on that page isn't neccesary. I've got by for a long time without ever considering that - however it may be that I'm just used to a bad system (and that this technique is an improvement that should be embraced). I think in the short term you are opening yourself up to a world of pain though (in terms of supporting older browsers). Thanks for the link (and you may wish to disregard my answer as it doesn't strictly answer your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking us if you should use the standard approach, or the non-standard approach. The answer is going to be: use the standard approach. Otherwise, you'll always be fighting CSS.

The best analogy I found for the 'standard' mox model is to pretend you're looking for a box to ship something and need to figure out the space needed. Your object is going to be a certain size, and then you need to leave room for all of your packing materials (the padding).

EDIT:

I admit that I wasn't all that familiar with that CSS property. After doing some research, it does seem to have practical uses (especially when trying to divy up columns in a fluid layout). That said, I wouldn't call it a replacement for the standard box model, but rather an alternative to use when it makes sense to use it. Learn the standard box model, and then you'll know when it makes sense to alter it.

Comment: I suppose a sub-question would be whether there are any signs on the horizon about whether the standard W3C box model is going to stay as it is or whether there is a chance that it may change. Question edited to reflect that.

Comment: It's taken well over a decade to get browsers to more-or-less finally support the current standard. It's not changing any time in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a css reset (as is fairly standard practice) this become much less of an issue.
These are two of the most popular

'The Meyer' - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

'YUI Reset' - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

These will remove all browser default styling, giving you a 'blank canvas' on which to build. You'll find the majority of CSS frameworks (and most sites) will use a reset of some description. With YUI they even give you another stylesheet to build back some of the removed styles (in a cross browser consistent way).

As for Padding/Margin/Borders specifically (which is what you really asked about in the first place) - it really depends on the context. They exist for different reasons - for example I tend to use margin when spacing divs, and padding when spacing headings but there are no hard and fast rules.